# VoIP over 3G on iPhone, what's changed in the SDK?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, voip, iphone-sdk-3.2

I've been looking at the SDK3.2 to find out about the new capacity to direct call over IP on 3G network, but I don't see anything obvious in the API diffs. Is this just something Apple allows on a low level private framework or does it reflect on the public frameworks as well? if so, which framework, class, method?

thanks for you help

Answer (score 2):

I don't think anything has changed. Its mainly a licensing restriction likely imposed by cell phone carriers.

Comment: Then why Skype is saying that after reviewing the SDK 3.2, they know now that it's feasible. Confusing...

Comment: @Stephane: fring is already working on 3G. I think Skype wants to make other changes to the app too.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is something Apple enforced at the API level. It's not easy to distinguish an encrypted VoIP data stream from other kinds of encrypted data and you could circumvent such a restriction very easily. They required the VoIP applications to enforce it themselves to get past the App Store review. They simply won't enforce this restriction on apps anymore. Actually, some apps already work on 3G without an OS update.